# Informatica Case Statement with date

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to do a case statement with three columns which are 30_Pst_Due_dt, 60_Pst_Due_dt, 90_Pst_Due_dt. I need it to do when 30_pst_Due_dt is between 1 and 29 then '1-29 days'. When 60_Pst_Due_dt is between 30 and 59 then '30-59 days', when 90_Pst_Due_dt between 60 and 89 then '60-89 days'.

I have wrote the following in informatica but I got an Pm parse Error:
IIF(30_Pst_Due_dt between 1 and 29, '1-29 days', IIF(60_Pst_Due_dt between 30 and 59, '30 - 59 days', IIF(90_Pst_Due_dt between 60 and 89, '60 - 89 days')))

Answer (score 1):

Between doesn't work in infa. You need to use old school `>=` and `<=`.

Since you mentioned pst_due is a date column, add few variable ports to calculate date difference with sysdate. And then use that in the iif clause to calculate final bucket.

```
v_30_Pst_Due_dt(int)= date_diff(30_Pst_Due_dt,SYSDATE,'D')
v_60_Pst_Due_dt(int)= date_diff(60_Pst_Due_dt,SYSDATE,'D')
v_90_Pst_Due_dt(int)= date_diff(90_Pst_Due_dt,SYSDATE,'D')
Out_bucket (string)=
IIF(v_30_Pst_Due_dt >= 1 and v_30_Pst_Due_dt <=29, '1-29 days', 
IIF(v_60_Pst_Due_dt >= 30 and v_60_Pst_Due_dt <=59, '30-59 days', 
IIF(v_90_Pst_Due_dt >= 60 and v_90_Pst_Due_dt <=89, '60-89 days'
)))
```

Pls make sure to add rest of your port just like 30_past_due calculation.

Comment: Hi Koushik, thanks for the help. The output column is date data type. Would I have to use To_Date() for it to work

Comment: Thats why if you provide some sample data and expected output it will be easier to write iif. If *_dt column is a date and you are comparing with sysdate, then if will be significantly different.

Comment: if the dataType of the column id 'DATE', then the value of this column should in date format too

Comment: Changed the answer assuming the date column.